# Argument error in Rails w/ Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, arguments

I'm using Sorcery (0.8.2) and Rails (3.2.13). I'm creating a form with a username label and textfield. I am using sorcery for authentication purposes.

I get the following error when trying to go to my 'login' page at `http://localhost:3000/login`:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)
```

The browser says theres a problem at *line 6*:

```
3: <%= form_tag author_sessions_path, method: :post do %>
4:  <div class="field">
5:      <%= label_tag :username %>
6:      <%= text_field :username %>
7:      <br />
8:  </div>
9:  <div class="field">
```

When I click the 'login' link, I immediately get this error. Does anyone have any experience with the wrong num of arguments and a text field?

Comment: What exactly is your error?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have created your user and did not activated him. Call the method:

```
 @user.activate!
```

as described here: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/User-Activation